# Teiid Springboot security context in DDL

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, teiid

In our Teiid Springboot project we have Spring Security enabled which has roles in it. E.g. GrantedAuthorities.

How can use/read those roles into a DDL VDB? Is there a Teiid function to read those roles or do we have to create our own UDF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `hasRole` function, it returns a true if authenticated user has the specified role. See http://teiid.github.io/teiid-documents/master/content/reference/r_security-functions.html